# Slow debugging with Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I've tried Swift3, it looked nice. 
After adding some Swift code to existing Objc/C++ codebase (pretty large one), terrible debug delays began to happen.

If I write

```
assert(false);
```

somewhere, the message about it appears in console, and Xcode reaches breakpoint after 2 minutes (so I can see exact place of failure, observe variables and so on).

After discarding Swift code (so there're only Objc/C++ files), debugging is just 2-3 times faster. 
I have to wait 30 seconds to reach function on button click:
[image]

After searching for it, I suppose the problem is with Xcode 8.3.2.

1. Have you met this problem?
2. Do you know of some new compiler/debugger flags, which speed up debugging?
3. Is it proper (for development process efficiency) to add Swift to such codebase?

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty large"?

Comment: @d4Rk 600+ source files, 5+ build targets with dependencies

Comment: I can just compare this to one of my unity 3d projects which outputs about 300 C++ files, and also contains some objective-c and swift stuff. But debugging speed seems to be ok there. I would say, that even 30 seconds are a horrible long time.. But really hard to say, as there may be a lot of possible reasons :/